# How to convert a date (Thu 31 Oct 2019 10:08:29) format to Milliseconds (1572516509000) in Load runner (Vugen)

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

During my scripting in Vugen (Web/HTTP-HTML), I have captured the time in date format (Thu 31 Oct 2019 10:08:29) in parameter file using date-time format (%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S). The value I have to pass in the Body section of web_custom_request, it accepts only milliseconds (1572516509000). How we can convert this date format to milliseconds in LR.

Can anyone suggest to me here?

Thanks,
Soumen

Comment: Can you use TruWeb protocol instead?

Answer (score 1):

Help to understand the use case.  Do you need to have the time in milliseconds at the time of submission?   At some time in the past for a given date and time?   At some point in the future for a given date and time?

The reason why I ask is that there are built in functions for generating a UNIX styled timestamp for the current time.   You could potentially plus or minus some number of milliseconds off of this for dates in the past or future depending upon the nature of the request: 86,400,000 milliseconds in a day

Comment: Or, see the attached link for conversion from human readable format to Epoch: https://www.epochconverter.com/programming/c

Comment: Yes, the time will be in milliseconds at the time of submission. There will be 2 times (start time & end time). And both will be in milliseconds. Start time will be current time and end time will be same day plus 1hr 15 minutes. Yes, for the start time we are using web_save_timestamp_param("p_StartTime", LAST); functions.  But we are unable to convert end time (date format), which is captured from Date/Time. Could you please help me on plus thing.

Comment: End time = start time in milliseconds + 4500000 milliseconds (3600 seconds in an hour * 1.25*1000 )